# How to handle data from axiosResponse for it to be displayed on MUI cards?

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, formik

Data from axiosResponse to MUI cards

Hello. I'm working on a small university project which requires me to create a Formik form in which I will be getting a fruit name which then will be used as to get a response from a certain API (https://www.fruityvice.com/api) using axios.get. I need this to happen onSubmit of my Formik form and return an object of some kind containing information about the Fruit's name and nutrients info because I need this data to be displayed using MUI cards on the main page - which should be handled by the App.js file. The problem is, I can't get this to work and have been struggling to handle the data that I get from the API. I don't really know what to do anymore. My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, useFormik } from 'formik';
// import axios from 'axios';
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Button, Card, CardContent, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const API_URL = 'https://www.fruityvice.com/api';
const axios = require('axios');

function FormikMaterialUI({ fruits, totalWeight, setFruits, setTotalWeight }) {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            fruitName: '',
            fruitWeight: 0,
        },
        validationSchema: yup.object({
            fruitName: yup.string()
                .max(100, t('invalidName'))
                .required(t('requiredField')),
            fruitWeight: yup.number()
                .min(1, t('invalidWeight')),
        }),

        onSubmit: (values) => {
            const weight = values.fruitWeight;
            const fruit = values.fruitName;
            if (totalWeight + weight <= 400) {
                fetchFruitData(fruit)
                    .then((newFruit) => {
                        setFruits([...fruits, newFruit]);
                        setTotalWeight(totalWeight + weight);
                        formik.resetForm();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    });

    const fetchFruitData = async (fruit) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/fruit/${fruit}`);
            const { name, nutritions } = response.data;
            const newFruit = { name, nutritions };
            return newFruit;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <div style={{ display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1, 2fr)", gridGap: "16px" }}>
                    <TextField
                        id="fruitName"
                        name="fruitName"
                        label={t('fruitName')}
                        type="text"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                        value={formik.values.fruitName}
                        error={formik.touched.fruitName && Boolean(formik.errors.fruitName)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.fruitName && formik.errors.fruitName}
                        style={{ margin: "8px 16px", backgroundColor: "peachpuff" }}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        id="fruitWeight"
                        name="fruitWeight"
                        label={t('weightGrams')}
                        type="number"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                        value={formik.values.fruitWeight}
                        error={formik.touched.fruitWeight && Boolean(formik.errors.fruitWeight)}
                        helperText={formik.touched.fruitWeight && formik.errors.fruitWeight}
                        style={{ margin: "8px 16px", backgroundColor: "peachpuff" }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" style={{ margin: "0 auto", backgroundColor: "green" }}>
                        {t('addFruit')}
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <p>{totalWeight}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default FormikMaterialUI;
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too general a description of the error, you need to add console.log() to the sequence
calls and specify what exactly does not work.

Comment: make your onSubmit async `onSubmit: async(values) => {` and add `await` before `fetchFruitData(fruit)`